# Perl: что за кодировка?

Tags: кодировка, perl

Логи в `Trillian` лежат в чудной кодировке, разгадать не могу.
вот строчка с переносом строки:

```
my $str = '1. какой то
глюк с фтп.';
```

должно получиться:

```
1%2E%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%BE%0A%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BA%20%D1%81%20%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BF%2E
```

Comment: **[URLDecode][1]**


  [1]: http://www.string-functions.com/urldecode.aspx

Comment: и что мне это дает? я знаю что тут напсиано. я не могу воспроизвести кодирование на перле.

Comment: вот оно - http://www.perlhowto.com/encode_and_decode_url_strings

Comment: KoVadim, ну я же написал и строчку и что должно получится. То что Вы предложили я конечно же пробовал ;(

Comment: я взял и специально сравнил. Он только точку не закодировал. Все остальное прекрасно и правильно закорировалось. Возможно, Вы пытаетесь запустить все это под виндой (на что намекает триллиан), а как там по умолчанию с utf -  я не знаю. Также неведомо, какая у Вас версия перл.


Также, если Вы пишете, что у Вас не работает, пишите что именно не работает. Возможно, показав результат, Вы ответите на все вопросы.

Телепаты уехали подальше.

Comment: # print -ln "1. какой то" "глюк с фтп." | perl -0777 -MURI::Escape -lne 'print uri_escape($_)' | perl -plne 's#%(..)#chr(hex$1)#gsme'
1. какой то
глюк с фтп.
#

Comment: @arto - научитесь корректно вставлять текст программы и писать более развернутые ответы.

Отредактируйте Ваш коментарий.

Comment: KoVadim, совершенно верно. в данном примере только точка. но ведб могут быть и другие символы.

Comment: по такой короткой строке сложно угадать, какие ещё символы триллиан кодирует, а какие нет. Точку кодировать в данном случае вообще то не нужно, но кто знает, как там программисты накодили. Вообще то я думаю, что если там оставить с точкой, то триллиан проглотит и не поперхнется (если там только нет проверки crc).

Но если посмотреть в доки, то `uri_escape` параметром может получать диапазон символов для кодирования. Вот к примеру

    my $encode = uri_escape($str, "^A-Za-z0-9\-_~");

@arto - и не нужно никакого повторного запуска перла:)

Comment: проверил. Вы правы, проглотил точку и не поперхнулся. чего то я сам не проверил это. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
# print "1%2E%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%BE%0A%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BA%20%D1%81%20%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BF%2E" | perl -plne 's#%(..)#chr(hex$1)#gsme'
1. какой то
глюк с фтп.
#
```

Comment: мне надо обратно, не раскодировать а закодировать.

Comment: perl -0777 -pne 's#[^\w]#''%''.hex(ord$&)#gsme'

Comment: Ну или через sprintf без квадратных скобок с аналогичным результатом:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\W/sprintf("%%%02X", ord $&)/ge'
```

Аргумент -n не нужен, потому что уже есть -p. Как и модификаторы m и s в регулярном выражении — работает и без них.